# how to generate option values in Playframework Form helper @select

Tags: forms, playframework-2.1

i want  to generate a `<select>` tag in Play `Form`. but the `option` values are not fixed. so i coded it as this:

```
@select(
    myF("server_id"),
    options(
        for(s <- servers){s.getId -> s.getName}
    )
)
```

however, the compiler tells out that:

```
Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to (Unit)
```

cannot i use `for` sub in `option`?  and how should i code? thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@select`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.select%24) takes a sequence of `(String, String)` tuples.  You already have a sequence (`servers`), so you just to map them to tuples:

```
@select(
  myF("server_id"),
  servers.map(s => s.getId -> s.getName)
)
```

Comment: thank you. i am a java developer and new to scala. it's very nice of you and your answer.