# Playframework [Java]: Populate select option by code

Tags: java, select, playframework

In my views I want to populate a select dropdown. This code works:

```
<select class="form-control"
id="pays" style="margin-left: 43px; width: 250px;"
name="paysnaiss" onchange="">
@for(element <- allPays){
<option value="@element">@element.nomFrFr</option>
}
</select>
```

However I want to use this:

```
@select(studentForm("Lnaiss"), @for(element <- allPays), options(@element),
   'value -> ""@element" -> @element.nomFrFr"[any value that should be selected by default]),'_label -> "Country name", '_default -> "-- Select Country --")}
```

And I do get the following error:

> illegal start of simple expression

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get an issue to my problem according to this link of [James Roper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672672/7895172).

The following code worked for me, hope that helps someone:

```
@select(studentForm("lnaiss"),allPays.map(s => s.nom_fr_fr -> s.nom_fr_fr))
```